# Javascript: Why doesn't getElementById(theID) work with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't `getElementById(theID)` work with `innerHTML`?

Works:

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById(theID).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0000/zn3zr86k/)**

`getElementById(theID)` works with `style.display`:

```
<style>
h2 {
    display: inline;
}
.openclose {
    cursor: pointer; /* or: hand; */
    margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .image {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
function openClose(theID) {
    if (document.getElementById(theID).style.display == "initial") {
        document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "none"
        document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "[+]"
    } else {
        document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "initial"
        document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "[&ndash;]"
    }
}</script>

<h2>Heading - 1st</h2><span class="openclose" onClick="openClose('a1')">[+]</span>
<br /><br /><img id="a1" class="image" src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABAAgMAAADXB5lNAAAAC
VBMVEX///8AAAD/AADAyZ2wAAAAg0lEQVQ4y73QsQnEMBBE0bFByeVqQlW4BAWa5KpxKZcciK3SA
1IBg4z9E7EvWMTixRJVvQUaShf6kBtQ+ng9SOz4RPxQWF04YraZkHjsWqA158a6CBW7ZsmJ9CTEg
LDhGzF+GvG3gbN1IJsOrQNn0gMJBkCzB8iYNdjQ5usDOMMCvNYFYQmUU1ZqYuIAAAAASUVORK5CY
II=">

<br /><br />
<h2>Heading - 2nd</h2><span class="openclose" onClick="openClose('a2')">[+]</span>
<img id="a2" class="image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

As tested [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_output_dom).

Additionally is it possible to ambiguate `getElementsByTagName("span")[0]` to something like `getElementsByTagName(theTagName)[theIndexNumber]`?

Comment: Where is `theID` coming from?

Comment: Missing value for theID

Comment: theID won't work. You will need to pass the value of the Id attribute. Here is your fiddle modified and working : http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/zn3zr86k/2/

Comment: "theID" is a argument passed to the function openClose(). In the onclick event of <span> tag, you call this function with the argument "a1". Hence it works there. But in your jsfiddle code, "theID" is an undefined variable and hence it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `theID` as a parameters.

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction('demo')">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction(theID) {
    document.getElementById(theID).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5ae2uwe/

Comment: Why lookup the element if you can just pass in `this`?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not using the correct ID ('demo') and instead using a variable which doesn't appear to be set anywhere in your example. Another tip, since you're calling onClick on the p element you can reference it with 'this' instead of doing another document lookup.

```
this.innerHTML = "Paragraph changed";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `myFunction` is expecting the ID of the element whose content to be changed as a parameter, but you are not passing it

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction('demo')">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction(theID) {
    document.getElementById(theID).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r0bw91nm/)

Answer (score 1):

See the below code. the variable "theID" is passed a value of the id of

tag. Now this variable is passed to the getElementById() function.

This is just for explanation purpose and this is considered as bad coding.

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var theID = "demo";
    document.getElementById(theID).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>
```

To answer your other question:

> Additionally is it possible to ambiguate
>   getElementsByTagName("span")[0] to something like
>   getElementsByTagName(theTagName)[theIndexNumber]?

getElementsByTagName() returns an array of elements. Hence you could use something like:

> getElementsByTagName(theTagName)[theIndexNumber]

But ensure, the function call has returned atleast one element and the variables "theTagName" and "theIndexNumber" has right values.